# Asp.Net Mvc Uniq Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller, routes

I am creating a site which is personel blog. I want to give a specific routing when I enter a new blog in admin panel. Normally when I save it matches the database id. I do not have access to static routing anyway.

I want the link parameter to be stored in the database when the blog is being entered via the routing

Default : localhost/ControlName/ActionName/id (localhost/Blog/GetBlogs/2)

bu I want that

Wanted : localhost/ControlName/ActionName/storedValue(localhost/Blog/GetBlog/bluesky)
or
localhost/storedValue(localhost/bluesky)

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is a slug. You just have to add a property on your blog class to hold some unique string value that will compose part of the URL. For example:

```
[Index]
[StringLength(80)]
public string Slug { get; set; }
```

Then, when creating the blog, you either manually specify the value for `Slug` (make it a field in the form) or compose it by "slugifying" the title of the blog or something. I use the following string extensions:

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string s)
{
    s = s ?? string.Empty;
    if (s.Length > 0)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[s.Length];
        int charIndex = 0;

        s = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = s[i];
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                chars[charIndex++] = c;
        }

        return new string(chars, 0, charIndex).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
    }

    return s;
}

public static string Slugify(this string s, int maxLength = 80)
{
    s = s ?? string.Empty;
    //First to lower case
    s = s.ToLowerInvariant().RemoveDiacritics();
    //Replace spaces
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s", "-", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    //Remove invalid chars
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^a-z0-9s\-_]", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    //Trim dashes from end
    s = s.Trim('-', '_');
    //Replace double occurences of - or _
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"([\-_]){2,}", "$1", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    while (s.Length > maxLength)
    {
        var pieces = s.Split('-');
        pieces = pieces.Take(pieces.Count() - 1).ToArray();
        s = string.Join("-", pieces);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Then, for example, you could do something like:

```
blog.Slug = blog.Title.Slugify();
```

However you create the slug, you'll then use the URL param to look up the blog by that:

```
public ActionResult GetBlog(string slug)
{
    var blog = db.Blogs.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Slug == slug);
```

This is why the `Slug` property is decorated with `[Index]` above. That makes EF create an index for the column when it creates the table/adds the column. Any column you intend to query on should be indexed for performance reasons. Also, you have to define a set length for the column, as NVARCHAR(MAX) (the default column type for a string) cannot be indexed.

Comment: Thanks for comment!!